# Should I be able to open the main loop of a Shimano Sora front derailleur?

Tags: chain, derailleur-front

Servicing my bike today. My chain does NOT have a master link but I was hoping to take it off and degrease it with popping out a pin. I've taken the rear derailleur side plate off so the chain is free on that end. I thought I could open this connection on the front (Sora) derailleur:

[image]

However, looking at the back it just appears to be a rivet:

[image]

Am I missing something? Is there no way to free the chain from this FD without breaking the chain either with a master link or chain tool?

Thanks.

Comment: Aside - the chain still won't come off the bike because it is threaded through the rear triangle of the frame.

Comment: @Criggie Face-Palm. Of course it wouldn't. I guess if the FD was a model I could open I would have figured that part out pretty quick.

Comment: Interestingly, there are some frames out there that use a raised chainstay, or combine the chain and seat stay into a single "rear swingarm" or "rear fork" such that the chain can come completely out with the wheel   But they're more MTB, and also tend to the IGH or singlespeed setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you’re not missing anything. That model of derailleur doesn’t split.

Split the chain with a chain tool this time and take the opportunity to install a master link.

Buy some master link pliers also when you do. Master links are hard to break by hand.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick reply. I already have master link pliers and a master link on my other bike's chain. I just don't have a master link for this bike so I thought if I could get it free of the FD without having to split it, that would be better. Oh well! Chain tool it is.

Comment: Follow: after splitting the chain and degreasing it, it turns out it DOES have a master link! The chain was just so filthy before that I couldn't spot it. Ha! Oh well. Now I know for the next tear down.

Comment: @ssilk my favourite master link (singular) was white.  It always clearly stood out and was quick to spot.  I've never found another one like it.